# Prioritising pallet racks in a racking system

Tags: anylogic

I am currently attempting to model a warehouse in AnyLogic. I have been using the Rack system with 5 pallet racks. I need the model to fill the pallet racks one at a time, i.e. currently when i initialise the model at 50% utilisation, all of the pallet racks are filled to 50% and i would like 2 and a half pallet racks to be filled up. Conversely, i would like the RackPick block to pick products from a single pallet rack until it is totally empty before it moves onto the next full pallet rack within the racking system. How can i achieve this? I am new to Anylogic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Also please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to do it with storing... You will have to do something similar with the picking.

You will need the following things:

1. Put the palletRacks in the order of priority in your rackSystem
2. Your agent will have a parameter called palletRack of type PalletRack with default value main.getPalletRack()
3. You need to create that getPalletRack function in main.

This function will use the following code:

```
for(PalletRack p : rackSystem.palletRacks){ //loops through the palletRacks of the rack system
    if(p.hasSpace()) //checks if it has space
        return p; // if it has space, return the palletRack
}
return null;
```

if you are familiar with this, you can also just have this in the function:

```
return findFirst(rackSystem.palletRacks,p->p.hasSpace());
```

Both do the same thing... but the second is not known by a new AnyLogic user

**Finally**:
In your rackStore, you will do the following:
[image: rackStore]